# Como posso obter acesso a objetos deletados no Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerenciamento de estacionamento no Django que registra o objeto 'Veículo' de acordo com seu tempo de entrada, e calcula o valor à medida que sai, porém necessito desenvolver um sistema de relatórios que retorne quantos carros entraram e o valor total do dia.

Como posso obter acesso aos veículos que deixaram o estacionamento, pois após o registro de saída, o objeto é excluído no banco de dados.

```
# models.py
class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False)
    horario = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.placa


class ValorEstacionamento(models.Model):
    periodoManha = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                              default_currency='BRL', default='2')
    periodoTarde = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                              default_currency='BRL', default='3')
    periodoFDS = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2,
                            default_currency='BRL', default='2.5')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Tabela de Valores"
```

```
# views.py
class EntradaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Veiculo
    form_class = InsereVeiculoForm
    template_name = 'entrada.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('sistema:veiculos')


class VeiculosListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'veiculos.html'
    model = Veiculo
    context_object_name = 'veiculos'


def saida(request, placa):
    veiculo = get_object_or_404(Veiculo, placa=placa)
    veiculo.delete()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

```
# forms.py
class InsereVeiculoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Veiculo
        fields = [
            'marca',
            'modelo',
            'cor',
            'placa',
        ]
```

Comment: Falta dados, cadê a classe de entrada de veículos e saída de veículos

Comment: Realizei a entrada e saída dos veiculos na `views.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para consultar estes dados, você precisara registra-los em algum lugar. Sugiro que, ao invés de deletar o veiculo após a saída, apenas o "desative", você pode adicionar um atributo "ativo" do tipo boolean em sua model, deste modo, você irá inativar o carro marcando o atributo como True ou False. Caso deseje fazer de um modo um pouco mais trabalhoso, porém, mais correto, você pode criar uma nova model onde você registrará as entradas e saídas do veículo, deste modo, o registro sempre estará em sua tabela de veículos, e, em outra tabela, você irá registrar apenas a data da entrada e data da saída daquele veículo vinculado o mesmo neste registro através de uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi... Para o Registro da Data, devo criar uma `class Data(models.Model):` que recebe o `data_entrada = models.ForeignKey(Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` e `data_saida = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`. E para o Registro de Entrada e Saida do veículo, eu não entendi muito bem como estruturar o modelo.

Comment: Você vai criar uma class Data como disse, e criara algo do tipo:

data_entrada = models.DateTimeField('Data de entrada', auto_now_add=True)
data_saida = models.DateTimeField('Data de saída', auto_now=True)
veiculo = models.ForeignKey('nomeDaApp.Veiculo', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

Assim você criará sempre um novo registro temporal de entrada e saída vinculado ao veiculo de modo que você só precisará cadastrar o veículo uma única vez, porém, poderá registrar várias entradas e saídas.